# Maximum Enters URL validation in form input text area

Tags: javascript

I have a form which takes URL OR Domains as values and retrieve page rank. Recently i have faced problem that Google started blocking the IP (It may be due to that someone started abusing the form) So i want to put 100 maximum URL check validation for this form

Please guide me

Comment: Hi Shahe, i have not tried anything yet, i was trying to find and java code which will check if user enter more that 100 URL's and display pop up saying, please enter 100 URL's. 2nd thing i see that the tool i am running for bulk check, many other people are also running with unlimited domains queries, google do not have any problem with them, just curious what method they will be using to escape from Google IP block for toolbar queires

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're wanting to do is pretty simple. There are a couple of things you could do to help prevent this on the client side.

**JavaScript**

```
var urlList = new Array();

if(urlList.length <= 100){
    // continue
}else{
    // fail
}
```

Resource: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_length_array.asp

The problem you're going to come across doing this with JavaScript, is if someone really wants to abuse your application nothing will stop them. It's best to validate this on the client side, pass it to the server side and validate it again.

**Server Side: PHP**

```
$urlList = array();

if(count($urlList) <= 100){
    // continue
}else{
    // fail
}
```

Resource: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp

Comment: Hi, is it for one URL, i want something to check 100 domains/url's like

Comment: I edited to reflect what you're looking for. The JavaScript doesn't change. You can just pass in an array of 100 domains and it should do the trick. The PHP you just need to use the 'count()' instead.

Comment: Sorry, i think i am not more clear when asking the question. What i am looking of user have not entered more than 100 URL's/Domains in text area box example abc.com than in next line abc1.com and so one upto 100 in 100 lines. Sorry i am not looking to check length of one entered URL/domain, i hope i am clear now

Comment: I changed the variable names. Maybe they were confusing you. urlList contains an array of URLs. If there are less than or equal to 100 items/urls in that array it'll pass TRUE. My script is checking multiple URLs in an array.

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate your help in this. i added if(($totalurls > 0) && ($totalurls <= 100)) it seems working